# check if user exists in file before login php

Tags: php, file, text, input

I have the following php code

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) 
      {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
      if (empty($username))
         {
         echo "Please enter a username<br>";
         } else $username = $username;
      if (empty($password))
         {
         echo "Please enter a password<br>";
         } else $password = $password;
      $text = $username . "," . $password . "\n";
      $fp = fopen('accounts.txt', 'a+');

        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && fwrite($fp, $text))  {
            header('Location: login.html');
            }
         fclose ($fp);
     }
    ?>
```

I am asking the user to create a login for my page so they have to input a username and a password.  I am taking the user info and storing it in a text file (I know this is bad but it is for educational purposes so i must do it) in the following format:

```
user1,password1
user2,password2
```

I am also error checking to make sure that the user inputs something into the inputs fields and if they dont i display a message on the screen telling them to either input a username or a password.
My question is how can i prevent users from using the same user name as some else so example

```
A user enter the following data
simon,password123
and another user enters 
simon,adminpassword
```

Right now this is allowed but how do i make it so it is not allowed in my code.

Comment: Good Lord, I hope you know what you're doing in storing this inside plain text files. ***"Scary"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$path = 'accounts.txt';

if (file_exists($path)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($path);
    $contents = explode("\n", $contents);

    $users = array();

    foreach ($contents as $value) {
        $user = explode(',', $value);
        $users[$user[0]] = $user[1];
    }

    if (isset($users[$_POST['name']])) {
        // User exists!
    }
}
```